# Get the indices of the maximum value of each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have a dataframe `df` that look like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [101, 102, 102, 103, 201, 202, 202, 203],
        "type": ["A1", "B2", "B3", "A3", "A1", "B2", "B3", "A1"],
        "Val": np.random.randn(8),
    }
)

     id  type       value
0   101   A1    -0.238221
1   102   B2     1.051656
2   102   B3    -1.335417
3   102   A3     0.859323
4   201   A1    -0.819574
5   202   B2    -0.589278
6   202   B3     0.925917
7   203   A1    -0.044021
```

First, I applied the following aggregation to get the certain `type` of each `id`

```
    idx = df.groupby("id")["type"].transform(lambda x: x.str.contains("B"))

    df[idx]
    
    id    type      value
1   102   B2     1.051656
2   102   B3    -1.335417
5   202   B2    -0.589278
6   202   B3     0.925917
```

Now, here is my question. I need to drop all records for any `id` where `type` value is not the maximum. By maximum, I mean there is this precedence:

An > Ak where n > k. For example, for `id` *102,* *B3* > *B2*, so the row with *B2* type for the `id` *102* should be dropped. Please notice that for any `id`, initial dataframe does not contain any duplicate `type` column. That is, there is no such situation where we have two *B2* for id *102*. For example:

```
    id    type      value
1   102   B2     1.051656
2   102   B2    -1.335417
```

So, we don't need to consider equality situation on `type` column for any `id`.

What I've tried is this; which gives me the maximum values as I wanted.

```
df[idx].groupby("id").max()
      type  value
id      
102   B3    1.051656
202   B3    0.925917
```

However, I need to modify my **original** dataframe `df`, so that any other record other than the ones above has been dropped. And I need to do this operation for any `type` *A*,*B*,...*Z* In other words, I need `df` to look like this in the end.

```
     id  type       value
0   101   A1    -0.238221
2   102   B3    -1.335417
3   102   A3     0.859323
4   201   A1    -0.819574
6   202   B3     0.925917
7   203   A1    -0.044021
```

EDIT: Fringe case

There is one exceptional `type`, *BA*. And the precedence for that type is determined as follows:

There are limited possibilities for *BA* `type` value: *zBA* or *yBA*

Precedence here is *zBA* > *yBA*

For example

```
     id  type       value
0   102   zBA    -0.238221
1   102   yBA     1.051656
```

Output

```
     id  type       value
0   102   zBA    -0.238221
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull the letters and numbers into individual columns, groupby on the letters to get the maximum numbers, filter on the numbers and get your final dataframe:

```
 (df.assign(letter = df['type'].str[0], 
            number = df['type'].str[-1], 
            filt = lambda df: df.number.eq(df.groupby(['id', 'letter'])
                                            .number.transform('max')))
    .loc[lambda df: df.filt, df.columns])

    id type     value
0  101   A1 -0.238221
2  102   B3 -1.335417
3  102   A3  0.859323
4  201   A1 -0.819574
6  202   B3  0.925917
7  203   A1 -0.044021
```

Comment: Hello! That works, thanks. I ve a quick question though. There is one corner case on `type` column where it does not have `number` at the end. So, I was doing string comparison for that one. For example, the type is `U` and precedence for that type is determined by preceding letter. For example, `zU` > `yU`. Nevertheless, I believe I can map that type accordingly to fit into your solution like 'U2' for 'zU' and 'U1' for 'yU'. I would appreciate any other approach to that fringe case though. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Impressive.  This is one that I need to study.

Comment: @zodiac645, do you mind sharing that fringe case. my brain works better when I see the source data and expected output - the explanation then clicks (hopefully) :)

Comment: Edited upon your request, please feel free to join here if you have further questions
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231589/get-the-indices-of-the-maximum-value-of-each-group

Comment: I think your solution is pretty spot on. It would be interesting to see how it works when the data is mixed, i.e columns with letters, and columns without, and see the final output. But yes, your solution is probably what I would try as well

Comment: When there are columns without letters, the code fragment above is taking both rows for same `id` because "number" is the same for both `type` value, that is A :). I will just use a dictionary like `{"yBA": "X1", "zBA", "X2"}` and perform replacement on `type` column as a workaround. Luckily, there is no `X` type :). Thanks again!